# How do you maintain low energy impact when adding many SKSpriteNodes in a SpriteKit game

Tags: xcode, performance, sprite-kit, nodes, addchild

I've currently been working on a battle scene for my app similar to what you would see in pokemon, with HUD for each character (3 characters per side). For each label and image I have been using

addChild(SKSpriteNode)

adding each label and character to the screen individually. At its current state my screen has 70 nodes on it and my draw count is over 100 making things very laggy. What is a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `ignoresSiblingOrder` is `true` (use `zPosition` to control the layering and try to keep the number of distinct positions small).  If your sprite nodes have different textures, be sure they're in an atlas.  And avoid shape and label nodes.

Comment: If you are using the simulator, remember that the performance is not the same in the simulator. I recommend trying in the MacOs app or real device.

Comment: to elaborate on @bg2b 's answer each SKLabelNode will add a draw count